# How to parse sentence in android?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I want to make JSONObject like this( {"name" : "john" } ) from String s.

plz help me.

```
final String json = "dasdasdasdaddadadadswwqaadww{"
             + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\" "
             + "}";
```

I did,

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
```

but Android throws Exception...........

is there easy way to parsing this?

I used JSONReader and JSONTokener, But this method throws error when String data is ungrammartical

is there only way to use for or while to remove trash characters?

Comment: "dadsdasdsddasdad " part will not parse, you must remove all text before first {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
        String s = "dadsdasdsddasdad {\"name\" : \"john\" } ";
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("{"),
                s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! vote needs 15 reputation, So i couldn't..

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);
```